# How to can I set the Type of Service bits in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, header

I'm writing an application to send data over a network, and need to know if it is possible to set the Type of Service (ToS) bits in the IP Packet header. Anyone know if this is supported by C#, and if so how I should go about implementing it?

I know I can use a raw socket type and specify my own header, but I'd rather not have to do this as I'm only using TCP, so it seems a bit pointless to create an entire header just so I can set three bits, when it can be automatically created without these bits set.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work? (almost straight from TcpClient.Client help)

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
Socket s = client.Client;

if (!s.Connected)
{
   s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
                     SocketOptionName.TypeOfService, 2);
}
```

Not sure what value you want to set it to, but this should work...

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not too sure on the value though. Some experimentation is needed I think!

Comment: This doesn't work under XP and higher, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248611. The evil SetSocketOption returns without reporting any problem, but the TOS byte is not set.